# What to create an Android socks Proxy Server over the internet without rooting

Tags: android, server, proxy, socks

i am having bit of a trouble, i want to know if this is possible or not. let me layout the details

i want to create a proxy server on an android device and want to use it on my other android device over the internet,

Scenario: i have a friend living in the US who has an android phone and since the guy is not technical at all related to technology. So making him to do something about it kinda out of question. i can get anydesk access of the phone and set it up myself. since i don't have device physically in my hands. i feel like i have very limited options.

What i want to do is to make a proxy socks server on his phone and be able to connect to his mobile over the internet, similarly like buy a socks proxy online. but i want to configure in a way that i can use his mobile internet on my mobile phone using socks5 protocol but not locally, i want to use it over the internet. so i can use it anywhere i go.

Is this even possible, if yes then how i can do it, if you have any solution or further questions, please do let me know.

Thankyou

I tried multiple android apps but none of them seem to work the way i want them to work.

Comment: Sounds to me like yet another Peer-to-Peer VPN system (server/backend free VPN).

Comment: More or less, yeah you can say that. is there any solution ?